# How to checkout a revision by SHA-1 hash with pygit2?

Tags: hash, libgit2, vcs-checkout, pygit2

It is seems that Repository.checkout can only checkout a referenece.
**Can we checkout any revision in the repo by SHA1-hash?**
equivalent to "svn checkout -r" in subversion system

Answer (score 0):

The `Repository.checkout()` method does only accept references or reference names, but that's by far not the only checkout method. There's `Repository.checkout_tree()` which lets you specify which treeish you want to check out (so you can pass a tree, a commit or a tag).

Comment: Note however that it does not detach HEAD like `git checkout <commit>` would do